# Categorical description of dense homomorphisms of topological algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be topological associative algebras (no matter, in which sense, for example, over $\mathbb C$, with identity, and with separately continuous multiplication). Let us say that a (continuous) homomorphism $\varphi:A\to B$ is *dense*, if its image $\varphi(A)$ is dense in $B$.

> Is it possible to describe this property (of density of homomorphisms) in terms of the category of topological associative algebras?

For example, if we assume that $A$ and $B$ are just locally convex spaces then a morphism (a linear continuous map) $\varphi:A\to B$ is dense (i.e. $\varphi(A)$ is dense in $B$), if and only if $\varphi$ is an epimorphism in the category of locally convex spaces.

Not all epimorphisms in the categories of topological algebras are dense, but I suppose there must be a description of density in this situation as well. Does anybody know it?

Comment: A simpler version of this question is whether you can describe just plain surjective homomorphisms of algebras categorically (since epimorphisms are the wrong thing), which is the special case of your question when the topologies are discrete. In $\text{Alg}$ there are a few possible answers, e.g. these are precisely the effective epimorphisms. But I think all of these answers will also give you surjective morphisms of topological algebras (in the effective case, satisfying the additional condition that the codomain has the quotient topology). So I'm pessimistic.

Comment: If we take closed subobjects as given, then there may be a better chance of recognising the morphisms with dense image. For example, in $\mathbf{Top}$, the continuous maps with dense image are precisely the morphisms that are left orthogonal to closed embeddings.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: yes, but in this approach the question arises, what are closed subobjects from the categorical point of view?